# Calabash-ios - How to set location?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, calabash

I'm trying to set a location using calabash-ios, it is possible to set a location using the calabash-ios?

Have searched here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/02-Predefined-steps and found nothing.

-EDIT-

I found a solution,there is a method called **set_location**, you simply edit the 01_launch.rb file and use the following code:

```
Before do |scenario|
  @calabash_launcher = Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher.new
  unless @calabash_launcher.calabash_no_launch?
    @calabash_launcher.relaunch
    set_location(latitude: -23.884659, longitude: -46.099488) 
    @calabash_launcher.calabash_notify(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set location using following

```
set_location(latitude: #{value}, longitude: #{value})
```